# jBPM 4.3 Task Notification tag being ignored

Tags: bmp

I have a task with a notification entry but no emails are being generated and no entries in logs.  Emails from mail node work fine.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I have to do anything special to my  custom AssignmentHandler impl for notifications?

```
  <mail g="216,156,80,40" name="Send email">

        <to addresses="kevinmoodley@gmail.com" />

        <subject>Testing the mail activity</subject>

        <text>This message was sent by the jBPM mail activity tester</text>

        <transition g="-78,-18" to="User Review" />

  </mail>





  <task g="210,250,92,52" name="User Review">

        <description>User Review Task Description</description>

        <assignment-handler

              class="com.kevinmoodley.BPMTaskAssignmentHandler">

              <description>Review AI Process Failure Assignment Handler</description>

        </assignment-handler>

        <notification>

              <to addresses="kevinmoodley@gmail.com" />

              <subject>Testing from task</subject>

              <text>This message was sent by the jBPM User Review task</text>

        </notification>

        <transition g="-42,-18" name="CANCEL" to="end1" />

        <transition g="-42,-18" name="RESTART" to="end2" />

  </task>
```

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I figured out that the default MailProducer implementation, called MailProducerImpl, depends on jBPM's internal identity tables. It requires the users be created in these tables and that the task be assigned to a user or user group on those tables before notification emails are sent. Since I am using our existing Active Directory, I do not use the jBMP identity tables and hence get no emails. Solution: write my own implementation of MailProducer